# Conditional comments are not recognized by Outlook 2007, 2010, 2013 for table size

Tags: comments, conditional-statements, outlook-2010, outlook-2007, outlook-2013

I'm building a responsive email template and I'm having problems with getting Outlook 2007, 2010 and 2013 to recognize conditional comments. I have a main table that has a class called 'content' and it's set as 100% wide with a maximum width of 650px. I read in a whole bunch of sources that the following should take care of the problem when Outlook doesn't recognize max-width for desktop email clients:

```
<!--[if !gte mso 9]>
<style>
.content {
width:650px!important;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE]>
<style>
.content {
width:650px!important;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

I've tried so many different variations of the first section - without the ! or gte, parantheses (some sources had them), and duplicates of the first section with the 9 replaced with numbers that correspond to the outlook version number, as well as marking and unmarking them with !important next to the width specification, but nothing works. Litmus shows that all versions of desktop Outlook except for 2007, 2010 and 2013 go to a maximum width of 650px.

Is there any way of specifying that all and any versions of Outlook should be 650px maximum? I'm also having issues where Lotus Notes 6.5 and 7 are full-width and although it's not as crucial for those to look fine, if anyone has a solution I'd be extremely grateful. I'm a beginner at this so please explain simply, if possible :) Thank you in advance!